# Instagram username Regex for Swift

Tags: ios, swift, regex

I am looking for the regex to filter username just like the instagram usernames.

I don’t know much about regex but I can use it in my swift function.

As I know that regex algorithms changes depending on the programming language, so I need that instagram username regex for swift language.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instagram username rules

1. Two matches `@` mentions with no space between **@thebox193@discodude**
2. Matches with one `.` in them **@disco.dude** but not two `..` **@disco..dude**
3. Beginning period not matched **@.discodude**
4. Ending period not matched **@discodude**.
5. Match underscores _ **@_disco__dude_**
6. Max characters of 30 **@1234567890123456789012345678901234567890**

Regex

```
(?:@)([A-Za-z0-9_](?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]|(?:\.(?!\.))){0,28}(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]))?)
```

More information here
https://blog.jstassen.com/2016/03/code-regex-for-instagram-username-and-hashtags/

Comment: I am having "Invalid escape sequence in literal" error in swift

Comment: Instagram also doesn't allow all numbers only username

Answer (score 0):

This should work /^(?!...)(?!..$)[^\W][\w.]{0,29}$/igm

Fiddle for this: https://regexr.com/3cg7r